# Excel: VBA to copy content from cell in active row

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need help to assign a function to a button in excel.
What i want to do is have a button get the value of the first column in the active row and copy this to another cell, or better assign this as a "variable" to be used in a lookup formula of a cell.

I have tried some variants, for example this:

```
Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Copy ("H2")
```

This gives

> Copy method of Range class failed

I'm a beginner in VBA scripting so I don't really know how to move forward with this.

Comment: first google search result is this: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that you are looking for something like this:

```
Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Copy Destination:=Range("H2")
```

Yet, you should insert a `procedure` for that purpose and not a `function`. So, the complete code (including a more explicit coding style) could be something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
ws.Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("H2")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

since you wrote you're interested in cells value:

```
Range("H2").value = Cells(ActiveCell.row, 1).value
```

Comment: @forschi: did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

Try with any of the below.

```
Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Copy [H2]
```

---

```
Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Copy Range("H2")
```